# Making SharePoint folder accessible over internet

Tags: networking, sharepoint, intranet, virtual-directory

I have a SharePoint document library on my intranet and I want o make this library accessible to users on internet. I know easier option is to just make the website internet facing but that is not possible for some reasons.
To workaround the thing I was thinking to map this document library to a folder on another server on intranet and make it a virtual directory; this server is internet facing and so the virtual directory can be accessed by the users.
Just wondering have any one got a better option or see any issues with this said approach?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the web application and essentially create an extranet web application that still require permissions.  Then you can grant the external users access to either the site or that document library with unique permissions.  Might be overkill but that could do it.